# Reprojection of raster for fused images

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am working on fusion of two different rasters. One raster is a multi-spectral band having spatial reference **GCS-WGS-1984** and other raster is SAR band having spatial reference **WGS-1984-polyconic**. Prior to fusion, I have registered multi-spectral band with SAR band. So spatial reference of multi-spectral data has been changed to **WGS-1984-polyconic**. After fusion, I want to compare fused raster with original multi-spectral raster. I tried for re-projecting fused raster to GCS-WGS-1984 in QGIS and ArcMap. **But during this process, size of my raster is changed from size of original multi-spectral raster.**

How do I overcome this problem in QGIS?

Comment: If you want a solution in either QGIS or ArcMap, you should post a copy of this question with the ArcMap tag.